# How to open this file

Tags: linux, web-apps, media-player

I'm trying to download a recorded radio-show that can be found in the following URL:
http://player.glz.co.il/Player.aspx?FixedPoster=true&FixedPosterName=GLZAOD.jpg&ClipID=150519-16&Type=aod&Width=300&Height=200
**For personal, non-commercial use only**, I hope it's not a violation of copyrights, if so I'll abort

I'm using inspect-element within developer tools in google-chrome browser in order to reach the files I believe they are the video-files of this video. If you will play the video and hit <kbd>ctrl+shift+I</kbd> you can see a list of files named `*.tsSeg1-frag1` and `*.tsSeg1-frag2` and so on..
I've built a script that downloaded all of these files. So now I need to merge all the files and convert all of them to a more standard format.

What I've already found out:

- I used the command: `file "file.tsSeg1-frag$x"` typed in my Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and the output was:`Apple QuickTime Movie (unoptimized)`
- I've Downloaded in the previously a bunch of similar files which ending with `.ts` extension from other sites and I could open them easily with a normal video viewer. The other sites' files' format as displayed with the `file` command is: `MPEG transport stream data`

I need help to find info about this file format and help me find a proper software to manipulate it.
The only resource I've found was this webpage:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2218/_index.html
And I'm not sure how much it could be relevant especially since I don't have a Mac nor Apple QuickTime-pro 7.

#### EDIT:

The URL at the top of this post points to nothing now. [Here is a link to a globally shared Google Drive link with those files downloaded but unplayable](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1L-L22KqHsxNUUwazRPQlNlQk0/view?usp=sharing)

#### EDIT 2:

I tried VLC and this was it's result when launched from the command line:

```
[0000562ee00e5f38] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000562ee0226c18] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0000562ee0226c18] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0000562ee0226c18] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> > [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f3b68c500c0] moov atom not found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f3b50c0ae60] moov atom not found
[00007f3b50c021f8] avformat demux error: Could not open /home/doron/downloads/GLZ.4-afternoon/19-5-15/1.ts: Unknown error 1094995529
[0000562ee01b6018] core playlist: end of playlist, exiting
[0000562ee0226c18] [cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: Interrupted.
```

This was the output when launching Mplayer from the command line:

```
MPlayer SVN-r37916 (C) 2000-2017 MPlayer Team
MPlayer SVN-r37916 (C) 2000-2017 MPlayer Team
225 audio & 460 video codecs
225 audio & 460 video codecs

Playing GLZ.4-afternoon/19-5-15/1.ts.

Playing GLZ.4-afternoon/19-5-15/1.ts.
libavformat version 57.71.100 (external)
Mismatching header version 57.56.101
libavformat version 57.71.100 (external)
Mismatching header version 57.56.101
libavformat file format detected.
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f341837f760]moov atom not found
LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
MOV: missing header (moov/cmov) chunk! Maybe broken file...
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f341837f760]libavformat file format detected.
moov atom not found
LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed


Exiting... (End of file)

Exiting... (End of file)
```

Comment: Aren't you better off using some 'audio grabber' while playing this?

Comment: I think the quality should be much better using a software that can decode these .ts files rather than use an audio-grabber of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) *should* be able to [play these](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/how_to_play_ts_files.cfm). However, .ts files seem to be rather special.

I have found two threads, one on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195107/ts-files-not-recognised) and another one on [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=865736) that might help out more.

Give it a try and let us know whether it worked.

Comment: A lot of time has passed since I wrote this post, the URL at the beginning of it points to nothing now. I edited the question with a link to a zipped file with all of those files I downloaded from that URL but I can't play.